# IE7 and jQuery: how can this not work? (.css())

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I am going crazy with some CSS IE7 compatibility issues, so I choose to go with javascript on that one.

Here is my code :

```
// fix ie7 menu
if ($('html').hasClass('ie7')) {
    var submenus = $('header .menu > li > ul.sub-menu');
    $.each(submenus,function(key,submenu){
        var w = $(submenu).width();
        $(submenu).children('li').css('width','300px');
        alert(key+" submenu li "+$(submenu).children('li').width());
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to force the ul.sub-menu element's children to take its parent's width (w). No luck, so I hard-coded the "300px" value for testing purpose. Then I tried with just "300". Still nothing.

How can my $(submenu).children('li') elements not have a 300px width?
I tested this code in Chrome and it works great.

Thanks.

Comment: $(submenu) should be just submenu

Comment: @karthikr no I am positive it shouldn't. Otherwise the width() method doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try, maybe, pure javascript? Something like `element.style.width='300px';` does that make any difference?

Comment: Tried with $(submenu).get(0).style.width="300px"; and no difference. Works fine in Chrome, nothing in IE7...

Comment: IE7 does not understand the HTML5 **header** element. Are you using the [_html5shiv_](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)? I am not sure if jQuery will be able to _select_  the **header** elements. Could you try with just `$('.menu > li > ul.sub-menu')`? Posted as comment as I don't know (and can't test) if jQuery works with HTML5 elements if the browser doesn't natively support them.

Comment: First, verify that you're successfully retrieving the submenus and the `li` tags. Showing the relevant HTML might help.

Comment: @andyb I am using html5shiv. Not sure either for the header elements, that was a smart guess, so I just tried with the selector you suggested. Still no luck.

Comment: @MattCoughlin I am, because I can alert() their width. It gives me the element's width, but ignores the .css('width','300px'); call...

Comment: @nax_: Have you validated the HTML? Different browsers react differently to invalid HTML. Again, it's difficult to offer much help here without being able to see the relevant HTML.

Comment: @MattCoughlin Here you go http://www.equinox-consulting.com/ if you hover on the "practices & expertises" top menu element in IE7, the <li> elements (with the border-bottom) won't have the right width. Should be the container's width, it's not. I wasn't able to correct it in CSS for whatever reason so I tried with JS, looks even worse.

Comment: Are you using HTML5 Boilerplate to add the `ie7` class to `<html>`? I've tested this in jsBin and cannot get `$('header .menu > li > ul.sub-menu')` to work in IE8 with `header` in the selector, even with the html5shiv. Also, how did you test the exact code above in Chrome as `$('html').hasClass('ie7')` will surely be false :-)

Comment: Yes, I am removing the $('html').hasClass('ie7') line for Chrome. But the ie7 class is working fine, I use it for my CSS fixes and IE7 displays the alert(). It's just the value that is displayed that is wrong. I removed the header selector and used var submenus = $('.menu > li > ul.sub-menu');. Once more, works in Chrome but not in IE7. The alert is still triggered though. I'm desperate! :-)

Comment: What happens in IE7 if you hard-code a fixed width for all submenu items in the CSS file (and remove the jQuery attempt at doing so)? Does the fixed width take effect in IE7? If it doesn't, that suggests a more fundamental issue with the CSS of the menu structure (something that may be specific to IE7), rather than a problem with the jQuery code. If it does work, next try using the exact same CSS selector to hard-code the values with a single line of jQuery code, and see if that works in IE7.

Comment: Any chance you can add the markup to the question or make a demo on jsFiddle or jsBin please?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('html').hasClass('ie7')) {
var submenus = $('header .menu > li > ul.sub-menu');
submenus.each(function(){
    var w=$(this).width();
    $(this).children('li').css('width',w+'px');
});
}
```

Comment: No, I do have to wrap it. Otherwise: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLUListElement> has no method 'width'

Comment: works fine in Chrome, still nothing in IE7, and I removed the "header" selector just to be sure